# Подстановка параметров в запрос

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Есть код:

```
  $query = "SELECT * 
            FROM articlePrev 
            WHERE articletype = ? 
            ORDER BY date DESC 
            LIMIT ?,?";

  $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
  $stmt->execute(array(1,1,5));
  return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Который должен возвращать пять первых строк из базы, но в итоге он возвращает пустой массив. Если подставить параметры напрямую, вот так:

```
      $query = "SELECT * 
                FROM articlePrev 
                WHERE articletype = 1 
                ORDER BY date DESC 
                LIMIT 1,5";
```

То записи выводятся. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Посмотреть в ошибки pdo? http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.errorinfo.php

Comment: первые пять LIMIT 0,5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, **array** в основном используется при **INSERT**.
Например:

```
        $len = count($manga_paragraf_name_a);
        $dbSet = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO m_paragraf (id_main, name, src_original) 
                                                VALUES (:id_main, :name, :src_original);');
        for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++){
            $dbSet->execute(array(
                    ':name' => $manga_paragraf_name_a[$i],
                    ':id_main' => $id,
                    ':src_original' => $manga_paragraf_href_a[$i]
                ));

        }
        $dbSet->fetchAll();
```

В вашем случае можно так :

```
 $query = "SELECT * 
                FROM articlePrev 
                WHERE articletype = ? 
                ORDER BY date DESC 
                LIMIT :start,:count";

      $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
      $stmt->bindValue(':start', 1);
      $stmt->bindValue(':count', 5);
      $dbSet->execute();
      $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
      return $result;    // можешь глянуть что пришло print_r($result);
```

Comment: Заработало, спасибо.

Comment: в основном - не означает, что не будет работать, где-то у него косяк.

Comment: Странно что заработало, articletype никто не устанавливает. Может, он просто другой запрос выполняет? :)